# How to make a part of text bold in resource dictionary

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have string defined in the resource dictionary as

```
<x:String x:Key="MyString">This is a resource</x:String>
```

in my xaml.

I use this string in TextBlock.

Is there a way by which I can make "This is" text as bold?

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource MyString}"/>
```

I can't use Run as this string will get translated for another language say German.

Comment: can you please double check your question again? looks like part it it is missed

Comment: Have you tried `<x:String x:Key="MyString"><bold>This is a resource</bold></x:String>` ?

Comment: @Daniel: I dont think that your edit is correct, since the user was specifically asking only for the part "This is" of his string to be bold and not the entire string. You changed the meaning of his question!

Comment: @NiklasS. looks like it, my bad, amended to make proposed changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style your string with [`inline document elements`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents?view=netframework-4.7.2) like [`<Bold>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.bold?view=netframework-4.7.2), [`<Italic>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.italic?view=netframework-4.7.2), [`<Underline>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.underline.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2) or even [`<Run>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.run?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Escape [`special characters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-use-special-characters-in-xaml) from your string.

Use `Inlines` attached property, which transforms your string to inline elements.

Example

```
<TextBlock local:Inlines.Text="{StaticResource MyString}"/>
```

Where MyString is defined like

```
<x:String x:Key="MyString">&lt;Bold&gt;This&lt;/Bold&gt; is a resource</x:String>
```

Result will be

[image]

Complete source code of Inlines attached property

```
public class Inlines
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Text",
        typeof(string), typeof(Inlines), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, OnTextPropertyChanged));

    public static void SetText(DependencyObject @do, string value)
    {
        @do.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetText(DependencyObject @do)
    {
        return (string)@do.GetValue(TextProperty);
    }

    private static void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject @do, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlock = @do as TextBlock;

        if (textBlock == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This property may only be set on TextBox");
        }

        var value = GetText(@do);

        var text = "<Span xml:space=\"preserve\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">" +
             $"{value ?? string.Empty}</Span>";

        textBlock.Inlines.Clear();

        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(text)))
        {
            var result = (Span)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are just a series of characters - they don't have any formatting, that's a display property.

If you want to display part of the text as bold, the simplest way is to split it into two parts, and bind them to separate `Run` elements within the `TextBlock`. This might cause issues when translating into different languages though, as the word order is likely to be different.

The alternative is to include some kind of formatting codes within the text string, and use a control that will interpret them into the required display characteristics. Using HTML and adding a web browser control to your window seems like overkill just to display some formatted text though. However, I did write about such a control, an extended textblock that will recognise a pseudo sub-set of HTML tags within a text string, in a recent [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-controls-formatted-textblock/).